# after() is wrapping quotes around injected HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the Javascript:

```
var bubbles = $('.history .bubble');
bubbles[bubbles.length-1].after('<div class="bubble me">' + text + '</div>');
```

Here is the HTML:

[image]

Any idea why anything I insert is being wrapped in double quotes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax:  `bubbles[bubbles.length-1]`

… gets you the raw DOM node and not the jQuery object.

This means you are calling the [DOM after method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after) and not the [jQuery after method](http://api.jquery.com/after/).

They behave differently!

If you pass a string to the jQuery method, it will try to parse it as HTML and then insert the resulting DOM nodes.

If you pass a string to the DOM method, it will covert it to a **text** node and insert that.

You want to call the jQuery method and not the DOM method, so use `last()` to get a jQuery object wrapping the last DOM node instead of the bracket notation you are using to get the raw DOM node:

```
bubbles.last().after('<div class="bubble me">' + text + '</div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of bracket notation use something like `.last()` or `.eq()`

### Demo

```js
var text = "X";
var bubbles = $('.history .bubble');
var qty = bubbles.length - 1;
bubbles.eq(qty).after(`<div class="bubble me">${text}</div>`);
bubbles.last().after(`<div class="bubble me">${text}</div>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='history'>
  <div class='bubble'>X</div>
  <div class="bubble">X</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`after` accepts either a DOM Node element, or a string - in your case you are passing a string hence it treats it as such and prints it out (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/after). If you pass a Dom Node object it will behave as you expect. Try this:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML="test";
bubbles[bubbles.length-1].after(div);
```

Comment: I think the jQuery `after()` is different than the JS version

Comment: they do, that answer refers to the use of the native JS after, I guess it's more appropriate for the OP to use the jQuery version in this case though